# This code for a system that is trying to determine a simulation result is not working

Tags: javascript, html

I am trying to make a calculator to determine something. What it does is not important, but I believe that I have some simple formatting error. What am I doing wrong?

```js
var x = window.prompt('Please input x');
var y = window.prompt('Please input y');
var a = window.prompt('Please input a');
var b = window.prompt('Please input b'); 
var u = 0.101(y/100)*480000(a/100)            
var j = 0.581(x/100)*120000(b/100)  
var preresult = j + u;
if (preresult < 177000) {
document.write('yes');
} else {
document.write('no');
}
if (u > 179999) {
document.write('fail');
}
```

Comment: What leads you to believe you have a "simple formatting error"?

Comment: `0.101(y/100)` tries to invoke a function calledd `0.101` and pass it an argument of `y/100`. What are you trying to do with this line? It seems as if you don't understand what functions are and how to invoke them and/or how to write mathematical expressions.

Comment: `What it does is not important` It's hard to propose changes to code unless we know what it is *supposed* to do.  I don't think this is answerable without a [mcve].

Comment: Did you look at the console of your developer tools?

Answer (score 0):

JavaScript does not see `0.101(y/100)` as a mathematics language - you need to specify that it is `0.101 * (y / 100)`. Also convert the `prompt` result to a number rather than a string.

```js
var x = parseInt(window.prompt('Please input x'));
var y = parseInt(window.prompt('Please input y'));
var a = parseInt(window.prompt('Please input a'));
var b = parseInt(window.prompt('Please input b'));
var u = 0.101 * (y / 100) * 480000 * (a / 100);
var j = 0.581 * (x / 100) * 120000 * (b / 100);
var preresult = j + u;
if (preresult < 177000) {
  document.write('yes');
} else {
  document.write('no');
}
if (u > 179999) {
  document.write('fail');
}
```

Comment: Thanks @ScottMarcus, fixed now.